# Handling string on Long type while binding variables in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, numberformatexception

In UI I have a field where user can put either number or '--' symbol. But my call to controller is failing with NumberFormatException exception when they put '--' as that field is defined as Long in my DTO. One possible solution is to change Long to String. I am curious if there is any other way to handle this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What number does "--" represent?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "--" would be zero:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/some/path/--", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String doSomething() throws Exception {
    return doSomething( 0 ); // assumming -- is 0
}

@RequestMapping( value = "/some/path/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String doSomething( @PathVariable( "id" ) long id ) {
    return "it worked (" + id + ")";
}
```

Comment: Sorry to not stating it clearly but this issue is on one of the many input fields I have in UI form. So I am using @RequestAttribute for binding input to fields in bean and I am not using /some/path/{id} path. And I am getting those exception on BindingResult. Any elegant way to handle this situation?